# How to append element in post function of compile - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So, this is my problem. I have two directives (say parent directive and child directive) and i am calling child directive from parent directive like this :

```
angular.module('components', [])
  .directive('helloWorld', function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         compile: function(element, attrs) {
              var x = '<directive2></directive2>';
              element.append(x);
         }
     }
   })
  .directive("directive2", function($compile, $parse) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(iElement, iAttrs, transclude) {
            iElement.append('<p>directive2</p>');
        }
      }
  });

angular.module('HelloApp', ['components'])
```

This works fine. But now i am writing a condition in post function of compile and when that condition satisfy, the child directive should append.

I just added the append function inside the post function, but its not working.

```
angular.module('components', [])
 .directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      return {
        post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var x = '<directive2></directive2>';
        element.append(x);
      }
     }
   }
  }
})
.directive("directive2", function($compile, $parse) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  compile: function(iElement, iAttrs, transclude) {
    iElement.append('<p>directive2</p>');
   }
  }
});

angular.module('HelloApp', ['components'])
```

I dont know what went wrong. Guide me friends

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/1285/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$compile` service before appending as below:

```
angular.module('components', [])
  .directive('helloWorld', function($compile){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var x = angular.element('<directive2></directive2>');
        element.append($compile(x)(scope));
      }
    }
  })
  .directive("directive2", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(element, attrs, transclude) {
        element.append('<p>directive2</p>');
      }
    }
  });

angular.module('HelloApp', ['components']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2zbabkjb/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try to define template to your first directive :

```
angular.module('components', [])
.directive('helloWorld', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<directive2></directive2>'
   }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But if i define the template, it will append the directive even if the condition inside the post function is false. I should append the directive inside the post function only

Comment: Ok, in this case you should compile manualy your template.
You should inject $compile service on your directive and write this : 
element.append($compile(x)(scope));

http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/1287/

Comment: can we call the directive inside the post function?? I need to call it inside the post function

Comment: What's means "call" ? My fiddle update compile the template '<directive2></directive2>' in post function. So directive will be "called" when the first directive compile the template. 
Maybe I don't understand your question